# ASP .NET MVC fundemantals video?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can anybody provide me the link to download free videos of MVC basics content given in the site

http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro.

Thanks in advance,
Adarsh

Answer (score 1):

There are links to the pluralsite videos on the left hand side of the page below

http://www.asp.net/mvc

EDIT: I think these videos are streaming only...no "download" option

Comment: oops, yup, I was searching in torrents for these plural site videos, I could only find for MVC 3 , none of the them for the basics:)